# Android: TextView background is stretched

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I want to achieve following layout:
[image]

My problem is that the background of the right buttons is stretched. It tried to do it like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/tab_gradient_background"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".1"
        android:background="@color/button_released"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/highscoreTextView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight=".7"
            android:background="@drawable/menu_button_background_released"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/highscore"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/menu_text" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/highscoreNumberTextView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight=".3"
            android:background="@drawable/menu_button_background_released_mirrored"
            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/menu_text" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

It looks like this:

[image]

Any ideas how to solved this?

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't that easy that I was thinking it would be, but I managed somehow to rectify this through "9patch" images. 
Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/highscoreTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="70"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/menu_button_background_released"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="High Scores"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/highscoreNumberTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="30"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/menu_button_background_released_mirrored"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="66"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/menu_button_background_released"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="High Scores"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="34"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/menu_button_background_released_mirrored"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="62"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/menu_button_background_released"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="High Scores"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="38"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/menu_button_background_released_mirrored"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: image 9 patch image version]

[image: mirror image 9 patch version]

Comment: Sorry, it is not working either. Can I send you the background images?

Comment: Yeah sure. this is my email address.
zohaib.hassan255@gmail.com